# Scaling Down a website @ 75% for resolution below 1368

Tags: zooming, scale

I've added that to the header of the site and this exactly what I want though it only works in chrome ..

```
<script language="javascript">
if(screen.width <= 1360) 
{
     document.write("<style>body{zoom:75%;}</style>");
}
</script>
```

Actually the zoom function only works in Chrome for now .. would there be any other way of achieving what I need to do :

Site URL: http://spassuisse.wpengine.com/les-bains/

```
@media all and (min-width: 1280px) and (max-width: 1400px) {
html {
zoom:75%;
}
}
```

I try to add a new media size within CSS .. but it's not working I want to scale the size of the size @ 75% for resolution in between 1280 and 1400px ..

I works it finds the point but it doesn't transform everything to scale down like you would zoom @ 75% within the browser.

https://www.elegantthemes.com/blog/divi-resources/how-to-identify-divis-responsive-breakpoints-and-fine-tune-your-designs-with-media-queries

like showed here but as opposed of setting the value for each H1 etc component .. juste scale that down @ 75% for those resolutions ..

Comment: I also tried that : @media all and (min-width: 1280px) and (max-width: 1400px) {
body {
zoom:75%;
}
}

Again this works in chrome but not in IE or ANY other browser..

Comment: Actually the zoom function only works in Chrome for now .. would there be any other way of achieving what I need to do :